# How to apply border to a anchor tag of a particular li using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to apply border to a anchor tag of a particular li. Currently i am using

```
li > a {
{
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border:1px solid black;

}
```

but this applies border to all a tags of li.

Comment: Can you add your HTML structure to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the li you want to use an ID.
so change your html to:

```
<li id="Hello"><a></a></li>
```

And your css:

```
#hello > a{
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign and use id of li or class of li

Using id of li

```
li#IDofLi > a {
{
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border:1px solid black;    
}
```

Using class of li

```
li.class-name > a {
{
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border:1px solid black;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an id.

```
<li id="my-li">
    <a>...</a>
</li>

#my-li > a {
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-child` for this purpose. Read more here: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

```
ul li:nth-child(2) a{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify, which `li` elements should be modified - using `id` or `class`, so:

```
<ul>
  <li><a></a></li>
  <li id="foo"><a></a></li>
  <li><a></a></li>
</ul>


li#foo > a { }
```

or

```
<ul>
  <li><a></a></li>
  <li class="bar"><a></a></li>
  <li class="bar"><a></a></li>
</ul>

li.bar > a { }
```